# How to model this function in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I want to train a feed-forward Neural Network with a single hidden layer that models the below equation.

```
h = g(W1.input1 + V1.input2 + b)
output1 = f(W2.h + b_w)
output2 = f(V2.h + b_v)
```

`f and g` are activation functions, `h` is the hidden representation, `W1, W2, V1, V2` are Weight matrices, `b, b_w, b_v` are respective biases.

I can't concatenate 2 inputs because that will result in a single Weight matrix. I can't train two separate NNs because the latent representation will miss the interaction between 2 inputs. Any help is much appreciated. I have also attached the NN diagram below

[image: NN Diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to write my own Linear layer which calculates `h = g(W1.input1 + V1.input2 + b)` I do this by creating 2 parameters W1 and V1 multiply input1 and input2 with the 2 parameters and then add everything. The code is given below:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import math


class MyLinearLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, size_in1, size_out1):
        super().__init__()
        self.size_in1, self.size_out1 = size_in1, size_out1
        W_1 = torch.Tensor(size_out1, size_in1)
        V_1 = torch.Tensor(size_out1, size_in1)
        self.W1 = nn.Parameter(W_1)
        self.V1 = nn.Parameter(V_1)
        bias = torch.Tensor(size_out1)
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(bias)

    def forward(self, x):
        w_times_x= torch.mm(x[0], self.W1.t())
        v_times_x= torch.mm(x[1], self.V1.t())
        weight_times_x = torch.add(w_times_x, v_times_x)
        return torch.add(weight_times_x, self.bias)  # w times x + w times v + b

    
class NN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch, h_ch, out_ch):
        super().__init__()
        self.input = MyLinearLayer(in_ch, h_ch)
        self.W2 = nn.Linear(h_ch, out_ch)
        self.V2= nn.Linear(h_ch, out_ch)
        self.act = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, i1, i2):
        # I pass in stacked input 
        inp = torch.stack([i1,i2])
        h = self.act(self.input(inp))
        o1 = self.act(self.W2(h)) 
        o2 = self.act(self.V2(h))
        return o1, o2

model = NN(5, 10, 5)
o1,o2 = model(torch.rand(2, 5), torch.rand(2, 5))
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if param.requires_grad:
        print(name, '->',param.data.shape)
```

output 7 parameters to be trained:

```
input.W1 -> torch.Size([10, 5])
input.V1 -> torch.Size([10, 5])
input.bias -> torch.Size([10])
W2.weight -> torch.Size([5, 10])
W2.bias -> torch.Size([5])
V2.weight -> torch.Size([5, 10])
V2.bias -> torch.Size([5])
```

Thanks for all the inputs @aretor, @Ivan, and @DerekG

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch let's you define your forward implementation in functional form, so you could do:

```
class NN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch, h_ch, out_ch):
        super().__init__()
        self.in1 = nn.Linear(in_ch, h_ch-in_ch)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(h_ch, out_ch)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(h_ch, out_ch)
        self.act = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, i1, i2):
        i = torch.cat((self.in1(i1), i2), 1)
        h = self.act(i)
        o1 = self.act(self.fc1(h)) 
        o2 = self.act(self.fc2(h))
        return o1, o2
```

And then have it being used as:

```
>>> model = NN(5, 10, 3)
>>> model(torch.rand(2, 5), torch.rand(2, 5))
```

Comment: Your solution has 6 parameters but I want to learn 7 parameters, as I mentioned in my question concatenating will result in a single weight matrix so according to your solution the hidden representation equation looks like this, `h = g(W.(i1+i2) + b)` and not `h = g(W.i1 + V.i2 + b)` also it does not work for different length inputs

Comment: @darthbaba What about adding another `Linear` module `in2` in the NN and then performing `h = self.act(self.in1(i1), self.in2(i2))` (`b` is equivalent to `self.in1.bias + self.in2.bias`). Standard feedforward neural networks don't accept a different length input, so you need to pad your input before passing to the network

Comment: @aretor self.act that is relu won't accept 2 arguments so the solution is to concat `self.in1 and self.in2` and apply a linear transformation to an h layer and then calculate o1 and o2 but the parameters to be learned increase by 3 that is `weights and bias of in1, in2, and h + weights and bias of o1 and o2 = 10` The other solution is define in2 like `nn.Linear(in, out, bias = False)` and then reduce 1 parameter

Comment: Can you tell us what is wrong with `h = self.act(torch.cat((self.in1(i1), self.in2(i2))), 1))`?

Comment: @darthbaba First, I made a mistake and wanted to write `self.act(self.in1(i1) + self.in2(i2))`. I wouldn't be concerned about learning 1 extra parameter (that is `self.in2.bias`), and you can still set `bias = False` on the second layer as you suggested (anyway, I would leave it, to lessen the learning burden of the NN). As for `W1` and `V1` I suspect there is a misunderstanding on what you want to achieve, so, please, add more details: e.g. does `+` means concatenation or sum? What are the sizes of the inputs? Etc.

Comment: '+' in the original equation of `h = g(W1.input1 + V1.input2 + b)` denotes sum and not concatenation

Answer (score 0):

I will point out that you CAN combine W_1 and V_1, provided that you simply tile them diagonally in a larger matrix and setting all other values to 0. You can then clip the weights after each optimization step to constrain these parameters to remain 0. Or you could use a sparse tensor to represent only the weights you care to change. In any case:

```
C = [[W_1   0]
     [0   V_1]]
```

as in, let W1 be a mxn matrix and V1 be a qxp matrix:

```
C = [[w11 w12 ... w1n 0   0   ... 0  ]
     [w21 w22 ... w2n 0   0   ... 0  ]
     [... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...]
     [wm1 wm2 ... wmn 0   0   ... 0  ]
     [0   0   ... 0   v11 v12 ... v1p]
     [0   0   ... 0   v21 v22 ... v2p]
     [... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...]
     [0   0   ... 0   vq1 vq2 ... vqp]
```

and:

```
a  = [[input1]
      [input2]]
```

(Please excuse dimension flip-flops if they exist, I didn't double-check). The resulting multiplication gives you the intermediate value you care about. `h = g(Ca + b)`

And likewise, I believe the second operation is identical to a normal fully connected layer. You can concatenate the final bias terms too, as the bias term is already defined as one parameter per output. `b_cat  = [b_w, b_v]`. That is, the following yield the same result:

```
f(W2.h + b_w) , f(V2.h + b_v)
f(C2.h + b_cat)

where C2 = [W2,V2]  # concatenated
```

So the only novelty is that you need to constrain some of the parameters in the initial concatenated weight matrix `C` to be 0.

Comment: This is a great solution but I think this becomes too complicated to handle for example we cant construct C as you have mentioned because we can't construct tensor of tensors with different dimensions that is if `C[0,0] is of size (h, input1) then c[0,1]` should be `torch. zeros(h,input1)` and then we have to stack with dimension 1 and again stack V1 with dimension zero resulting in 4D tensor which becomes hard to track in the optimization step, trying with sparse tensor also has the same issue. The only solution I can think is to write my own linear layer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "tensors of different dimensions". `C` as described is a `2x2` weight matrix so evaluates as a normal linear layer. In general, you can't expect a linear layer to accept inputs of arbitrary length as the dimensions of `C` (or `W1` and `V1`) must be fixed before training.

Comment: I urge you to create the C matrix in PyTorch, the conditions are as follows C has to be a tensor with `requires_grad=True` and the diagonal element has to be a tensor of size (10,5) with nondiagonal elements being zero

Comment: Perhaps you're misunderstanding what I mean by tiled diagonally. I'll edit my answer to be more clear